# Disabling AMD APU integrated graphics card in favor of the discrete NVIDIA GPU

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon

I would like to know a software based remedy to disable the integrated AMD APU graphics card in favor of the discrete one.

My problem is that whatever I seem to do I can never use the discrete graphics card, if a remedy is available to force a program to use the discrete one, that will also be accepted.

I am using the latest open source drivers supplied with Ubuntu Studio 20.04.

The chips in question are AMD APU A6-6210 and AMD/Radeon R5 240M

No BIOS setting is available to disable the integrated GPU in the APU.

Comment: K7AAY - no man, the GPU is also AMD/Radeon R5 M240!!! .... Wtf?! :D

Comment: To clarify further, what I am looking for is a way to disable the AMD APU's integrated GPU so I can benefit from the power that the R5 240M provides ... I simply don't want to spend the amounts of time required to see how to tweak that or whether it's even possible!
I do realize that it may prove to be rather impossible ... Also the fact that this laptop is kinda trashy anyway, it can no longer make use of FGLRX without "dependency resolution" - I can try but not soon anyway. 
Also there's no support in the AMD-GPU drivers for both integrated AND discrete cards!!! Trash!